# Show last N rows from input datafile only in \pgfplotstabletypeset

Tags: pgfplotstable

I would like to limit the rows in `\pgfplotstabletypeset` to the last N rows. I can skip rows by doing this:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[skip rows between index={0}{4}]{file.data}
```

But this only works if I know the total row count in advance. As the data file will grow over time I want the table to only contain the last, let's say 12 rows.
Truncating the data file is not an option as it is also used in a pgfplot where all rows are relevant.

Is there a way to calculate the second parameter to `skip rows between index` based on the total number of rows from the file?

Comment: The first column contains a date field in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`. Would a sequential ID help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a new style called `print last` that can be used to print only the last couple of rows of a table. You can specify the number of rows to be printed using the argument to `print last` (so `print last=3` will print the last three rows of a table). If you don't supply an option, just the last line will be printed.

The style works using the `row predicate`, which allows us to specify a chunk of code that is executed for each line in the table, and if `\pgfplotstableuserowfalse` is executed within that code chunk, the line will be ignored. During the execution of the code, the total number of rows is available as `\pgfplotstablerows`.

Here's an example containing the style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar} % For the date column
\usepackage{filecontents} % To be able to include the data in the .tex file

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
2011-01-01 5 7.1
2011-02-01 3 8.2
2011-03-01 4 9.1
2011-04-01 2 3.5
2011-05-01 3 9.2
2011-06-01 7 1.1
2011-07-01 7 4.8
2011-08-01 6 2.6
2011-09-01 2 2.7
2011-10-01 5 15.3
2011-11-01 6 4.1
2011-12-01 7 2.2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
%% The interesting bit starts
\pgfkeys{
    /pgfplots/table/print last/.style={
        row predicate/.code={
            % Calculate where to start printing, use `truncatemacro` to get an integer without .0
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\firstprintedrownumber{\pgfplotstablerows-#1} 
            \ifnum##1<\firstprintedrownumber\relax
                \pgfplotstableuserowfalse
            \fi
        }
    },
    /pgfplots/table/print last/.default=1
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    print last=4,
    columns/0/.style={
        column type=r,
        date type={\monthname\ \year} % Nice date printing
    },
    columns/2/.style={
        dec sep align % Nice number alignment
    }
]{testdata.dat}
\end{document}
```