# Remove rows in a \addplot table command

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Is there any way to adapt [Show last N rows from input datafile only in \pgfplotstabletypeset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31908/show-last-n-rows-from-input-datafile-only-in-pgfplotstabletypeset) to a `\addplot table` command ?

This doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
1 5
2 3
3 6
4 4
5 0
6 1
\end{filecontents}

\pgfkeys{
    /pgfplots/table/print last/.style={
        row predicate/.code={
            % Calculate where to start printing, use `truncatemacro` to get an integer without .0
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\firstprintedrownumber{\pgfplotstablerows-#1}
            \ifnum##1<\firstprintedrownumber\relax
                \pgfplotstableuserowfalse
            \fi
        }
    },
    /pgfplots/table/print last/.default=1
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[x=1cm]
    \addplot table {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[x=1cm]
    \addplot table [print last=4] {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Both plots are the same:

[image]

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Also, in this case you should also show a line without the `print last=4` to ensure that your graph is properly formatted (except for the `print last` part).

Comment: Sorry, MWE added.

Comment: Thanks. But that does not seem to produce the graphs for me. I get the axis, just not the blue lines. Also, minimal should not be used for a MWE. I'd suggest using the article class.  It seems that if I change the file name from `data.dat` to `data.data` works so not sure what is going on.

Comment: Changed to article class. It runs for me but if [print last=4] should work, the second plot ought to draw only the last 4 points of the table.

Comment: Excellent, now you have a full MWE. I don't know why I needed to change the name earlier. It appears that if I use this MWE in a new directory, things work fine. But in my usual directory where I place these tests things don't work with the `data.dat` file name, even though I checked the file and it appears to be fine... Anyway, my problem is unrelated to yours, so thanks for putting together a MWE.

Comment: The `row predicate` only applies to table typesetting. The plot tools rely on on "coordinate filtering". Perhaps a suitable solution would use `skip coords between index={begin}{end}`. Perhaps I can elaborate this later (unless someone has more time)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a style `plot last=<n>` that can be added to the `\addplot table [<options>]`. It uses the `create on use` syntax to create a new column which checks whether the current row is less than `n` rows from the final row, assigns the value of that check to `meta`, and then uses a filter to only keep the values for which `meta` is `1`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[x=1cm]
    \addplot table {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[x=1cm]
      \addplot table [plot last=4] {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

will yield

[image]

The main advantage over this approach is that you don't need to explicitly call `\pgfplotstablegetrowsof` before your plot, and you don't need to specify the data file twice. The main drawback is that you can't use the `meta` entry anymore for plotting error bars or changing the colour in a scatterplot.

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
a b
1 5
2.5 3
3 6
4 4
5 0
6 1
\end{filecontents}

\pgfkeys{
    /pgfplots/table/print last/.style={
        row predicate/.code={
            % Calculate where to start printing, use `truncatemacro` to get an integer without .0
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\firstprintedrownumber{\pgfplotstablerows-#1}
            \ifnum##1<\firstprintedrownumber\relax
                \pgfplotstableuserowfalse
            \fi
        }
    },
    /pgfplots/table/print last/.default=1,
    /pgfplots/table/plot last/.style={
        create on use/rows/.style={
            create col/expr=\pgfplotstablerow>(\pgfplotstablerows-#1-1)
        },
        meta=rows,
        /pgfplots/x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{x/meta}
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[x=1cm]
    \addplot table {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[x=1cm]
      \addplot table [plot last=4] {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Thanks Christian, you pointed me to a solution that works. This is the edited and corrected code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
1 5
2 3
3 6
4 4
5 0
6 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \addplot table {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{data.dat}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yfin{\pgfmathresult - 4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yini{0}

    \begin{axis}[x=1cm,y=1cm,skip coords between index={\yini}{\yfin}]
        \addplot table {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this producing the `<n>` coordinates? I thought you wanted the last `<n>` data values plotted? Also, it would be better to post a complete example with packages and `\documentclass`.

Comment: Fernando, I'm glad my comment helped out - you approach was precisely what I had in mind. But Peter is right: it seems as if you have (accidentally?) included rows 0 : (N-2) ... did you mean `skip ... = {0}{\yini}` or something like that?

Comment: It's true. Now it's fixed.