# pgfplots: Remove data points without changing the original table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to know a way to remove one or more data points from a plot, using pgfplots, generated by an external table "data.csv". In the minimal [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83888/how-to-plot-data-from-a-csv-file-using-tikz-and-csvsimple/83929#83929) below, I would like to remove the third point (3,5) without changing the original table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,4,5,1
2,3,1,5
3,5,6,1
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Also, it would be nice to somehow tell pgfplots to erase specifically the "third point", without telling the coordinates. Or at least, only providing the abcissa value. A similar feature is encountered in Origin software, where you choose the points to erase by hand.

Comment: possibly related/helpful: [Remove rows in a \addplot table command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35318)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily do what you want. Just use something like the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[skip coords between index={2}{3}]
        \addplot table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Notice that when you want to remove line 3, it is the first number (2) that identifies it, because if you have `...index={a}{b}` it removes lines with index `i` such that `a<= i<b`. This is true because we start counting at `i=0`, so the line you want to remove is indexed by `i=2`. You can add multiple lines to be skipped if you want, like:

```
...
\begin{axis}[skip coords between index={2}{3},
             skip coords between index={5}{6}]
...
```

This will remove data line 3 (`i=2`) and 6 (`i=5`)in the original file (not counting headers, and assuming you had that many lines). In your example, now with data in a seperate file, you could remove the first (0) and last (4) using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[skip coords between index={0}{1},
                         skip coords between index={4}{5}]
                \addplot table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

Comment: I have a follow-up question: If I have two \addplot commands, is there a way to skip different coordinates for each of the commands?

Comment: `\addplot table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma, skip coords between index={2}{3}] {data.csv};` can be used for individual plots.