# Animate PGF Plot from discrete data

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations

I have a tikz picture that contains data points (only a part shown)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength{\figurewidth}{8cm}
\setlength{\figureheight}{4.5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
            use comma,
            1000 sep={},
    width=0.951\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-1,
    xmax=1,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={xlabel},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={ylabel},
    axis background/.style={fill=white}
    ]
    \addplot [color=black, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
-1  0\\
-0.987  0.001\\
-0.823  0.15\\
-0.713  0.4\\
-0.684  0.5\\
-0.542  0.6\\
-0.478  0.65\\
-0.3544 0.7\\
-0.254  0.8\\
-0.14   0.9\\
0   1\\
0.057774545 0.9\\
0.15794 0.8\\
0.258105455 0.7\\
0.358270909 0.65\\
0.458436364 0.6\\
0.558601818 0.5\\
0.658767273 0.4\\
0.758932727 0.15\\
0.859098182 0.05\\
0.959263636 0.001\\
1   0\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The data is generated from measurements and can't be fitted (easily) with a single function or at least I'd like to avoid that.

Is there a nice way to animate (line plot) the data stepwise or in chunks of n points?

I would like to avoid manually generating

Image-01

```
    \addplot [color=black, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
-1  0\\
%-0.987  0.001\\
%-0.823  0.15\\
%-0.713  0.4\\
%-0.684  0.5\\
%-0.542  0.6\\
...
    };
```

Image-02

```
    \addplot [color=black, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
-1  0\\
-0.987  0.001\\
%-0.823  0.15\\
%-0.713  0.4\\
%-0.684  0.5\\
%-0.542  0.6\\
...
    };
```

etc. in order to loop those images. I would prefer an automated solution.

I would be using the beamer class and compile with XeLaTeX if this information makes a difference.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: I don't have a MWE. I elaborated on the method I would like to avoid with more detailed code if that helps.

Comment: It would be useful if you could add a compilable example that will produce the complete plot, including all the relevant packages. Not everyone who knows how to animate things in beamer also speaks `pgfplots` or wants to learn it just to find out what packages are needed.

Comment: That makes sense! I didn't think of that and thought basically any plot will do for me as an example as long as it containts negative, not evenly spaced x values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A animation with `beamer` on-board tools:

*The select macro was borrowed from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199396/36296*

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength{\figurewidth}{8cm}
\setlength{\figureheight}{4.5cm}

% Style to select only points from #1 to #2 (inclusive)
\pgfplotsset{select coords between index/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={
        \ifnum\coordindex<#1\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
        \ifnum\coordindex>#2\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
    }
}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\slide}{\the\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\animate<1-22>
\transduration<1-22>{0.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
            use comma,
            1000 sep={},
    width=0.951\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-1,
    xmax=1,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={xlabel},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={ylabel},
    axis background/.style={fill=white}
    ]
    \addplot [color=black, forget plot,select coords between index={0}{\slide}]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
-1  0\\
-0.987  0.001\\
-0.823  0.15\\
-0.713  0.4\\
-0.684  0.5\\
-0.542  0.6\\
-0.478  0.65\\
-0.3544 0.7\\
-0.254  0.8\\
-0.14   0.9\\
0   1\\
0.057774545 0.9\\
0.15794 0.8\\
0.258105455 0.7\\
0.358270909 0.65\\
0.458436364 0.6\\
0.558601818 0.5\\
0.658767273 0.4\\
0.758932727 0.15\\
0.859098182 0.05\\
0.959263636 0.001\\
1   0\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \pause[20]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great work! Almost exactly what I am looking for. Is there a way the animation can circle through all frames by itself, i.e. after opening the slide or clicking on it? For my presentation I have a lot more data points and I wouldn't like to click manually through all of them.

Comment: @idkfa The code above already should do that. With adobe reader in presentation mode it certainly works. At the moment, it's rather slow, but you can adjust the speed with `\transduration<1-22>{0.5}`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an animation of some datapoints from a table.
For the animation I use the [`animate`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate)-package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents}{mydata.data}
    X Y
    0 2
    1 4
    2 2
    3 5
    4 4
    5 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{animateinline}{2}% frames per second
        \multiframe{5}{ix=1+1}{% the +1 is the step size
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                        xlabel={X-Name},
                        ylabel={Y-Name},
                        xmin=0, xmax=5,
                        ymin=1, ymax=5,
                        ]
                    \addplot[restrict x to domain=0:\ix,red] table [x index=0,y index=1]{mydata.data};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

The result is (start and end view of the animation):
[image]

Requirements for animate:

- pdfTEX, version >= 1.20 or LuaTEX for direct PDF output
- Ghostscript, version >= 9.15 or Adobe Distiller for PS to PDF conversion
- dvipdfmx, version >= 20080607 for DVI to PDF conversion
- Acrobat Reader (version >= 7), PDF-XChange, Foxit Reader

**Edit:**
For looping the images afterwards you can set the option `loop` for the `animate`-package: `\usepackage[loop]{animate}`.

Comment: Thanks! XeLaTeX is able to compile your example, however if I change ´ix=-1+0.01´ I get package calc error `.' invalid at this point. My data contains negative values and the x coordinates are not evenly spaced. I can't compile with LuaLaTex (max-print-line 120 unknown -> lualatex.fmt missing -> pgfsys-luatex.def not found -> ...) Seems it does not work out of the box with Texniccenter and Miktex

Comment: The prefix `i` of the loop variable `ix` declares it an integer variable. For non-integers, replace `ix` with `rx`.

Comment: @idkfa For searchability it's best if you had asked a separate question for that, (but someone already did it, see [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628001/why-is-my-animation-not-working-with-tikz/628003#628003) – disclaimer, I posted an answer there)

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP uses the standard **`article`** class which does not provide the stepping facilities of `beamer`, this example makes use of the `animate` package to create the animated graph on a single document page (using samcarter's code with slight modifications):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}

\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength{\figurewidth}{8cm}
\setlength{\figureheight}{4.5cm}

% Style to select only points from #1 to #2 (inclusive)
\pgfplotsset{select coords between index/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={
        \ifnum\coordindex<#1\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
        \ifnum\coordindex>#2\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
    }
}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{animateinline}[controls]{2} % 2 frames per sec
    \multiframe{22}{idx=1+1}{  % 22 frames for 22 line segments
      \begin{tikzpicture}      % idx=1, 2, ..., 22
        \begin{axis}[%
          /pgf/number format/.cd,
                  use comma,
                  1000 sep={},
          width=0.951\figurewidth,
          height=\figureheight,
          at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
          scale only axis,
          xmin=-1,
          xmax=1,
          xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
          xlabel={xlabel},
          ymin=-0.1,
          ymax=1,
          ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
          ylabel={ylabel},
          axis background/.style={fill=white}
          ]
          \addplot [
            color=black, forget plot,select coords between index={0}{\idx},
            unbounded coords=jump
          ] table[row sep=crcr]{%
              -1  0\\
              -0.987  0.001\\
              -0.823  0.15\\
              -0.713  0.4\\
              -0.684  0.5\\
              -0.542  0.6\\
              -0.478  0.65\\
              -0.3544 0.7\\
              -0.254  0.8\\
              -0.14   0.9\\
              0   1\\
              0.057774545 0.9\\
              0.15794 0.8\\
              0.258105455 0.7\\
              0.358270909 0.65\\
              0.458436364 0.6\\
              0.558601818 0.5\\
              0.658767273 0.4\\
              0.758932727 0.15\\
              0.859098182 0.05\\
              0.959263636 0.001\\
              1   0\\
          };
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }  
  \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I apologize, I copied the MWE from my document to show the plot as samcarter requested ("add a compilable example that will produce the complete plot, including all the relevant packages") In the last paragraph of my question I stated that I'd use beamer + xelatex. Thank you nontheless! I'll try and recreate your solution as well.

Comment: No need to apologize. This works with any document class and with `xelatex` too.