# Why do I get "Package calc Error: `.' invalid at this point." error message in animation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

It seems that this animation is not working.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,tikzmark,patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}% <- if you have an ol

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,fillbetween}
\DeclareMathOperator{\CDF}{cdf}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PDF}{pdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{1}  %controls
        \multiframe{50}{i=-2.5+0.1}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{animateinline} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It gives me this output

```
! Package calc Error: `.' invalid at this point.
! Package calc Error: `.' invalid at this point.
! Package animate Error: Contents of first frame must not have zero width.
! Package animate Error: Contents of first frame must not have zero height.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case because the first letter is `i`, it can only take integer values.

> The prefix `i` of the loop variable `ix` declares it an integer variable. For non-integers, replace `ix` with `rx`.

Source: [Animate PGF Plot from discrete data](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351463/animate-pgf-plot-from-discrete-data#comment863639_351472)

Comment: Somewhat related: [calculations - Multiply the value by decimal number in latex? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52957/multiply-the-value-by-decimal-number-in-latex)